# Constructive version of Hahn-Banach in Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider a Hilbert space  and an arbitrary linear subspace  ⊆ . Moreover, let ′ ∈  ′ be a continuous linear functional.
Prove without using the theorem of Hahn-Banach that there exists a continuous linear functional
′ ∈ ′
such that ′
() = ′
() for all  ∈  and ‖′‖′ = ‖′‖ ′.

Comment: Actually you do not need even the Riesz representation theorem. You may assume that $V$ is closed, as by continuity you can extend $v'$ to the closure of $V.$ The space can be decomposed into the orthogonal direct sum $V\oplus V^\perp.$ So the only problem is to extend your functional to $V^\perp,$ so that the norm does not increase. There is one obvious choice.

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc....... Do I have to First extend ′continuously to the closure  of ? , and which theorem
from the introduction course for the Hilbert space should I use?

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer, actually Riesz's theorem employs Hahn-Banach.

Comment: @Kipre That's a generał fact of metric topology. Let $Y\subset X,$ where $X$ is a complete metric space. Assume the mapping $\varphi:Y\to Z,$ where $Z$ is a complete metric space, satisfies (the Lipschitz condition) $$d_Z(\varphi(y_1),\varphi,(y_2))\le c\,d_X(y_1,y_2),$$ for a positive constant $c$ and any $y_1,y_2\in Y.$ Then $\varphi$ extends uniquely to the closure of $Y$ and the Lipschitz condition is satisfied for the extension,  with the same constant $c.$  If you like, I can type the full answer to your question.

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc, Please do it...I will be grateful for that!

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Good spot, I didn't read the question carefully.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Hello, thank you for providing the full answer......Can I have your email id, I would like to contact you if possible.

Comment: If you do not mind I prefer to be contacted by  Stack Exchange portal.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $v'\in V',$ where $V'$ denotes the dual space of $V\subset \mathcal{H}.$  Let $W$ denote the closure of $V.$ Our first task is to extend $v'$ to $W.$ It is the standard procedure, which is described below, and can be skipped by those who are familiar with that.

For any $w\in W$ there exists a sequence $v_n\in V$ such that $\|v_n-w\|\to 0.$ In particular $v_n$ is a Cauchy sequence. We have
$$|v'(v_n)-v'(v_m)|\le \|v'\|\,\|v_n-v_m\|$$ therefore the numbers $v'(v_n)$ form a Cauchy sequence. Denote $$\tilde{v}(w)=\lim_{n\to \infty}v'(v_n)\qquad (*)$$
The value $\tilde{v}(w)$ does not depend on the choice of the sequence $v_n\to w.$ Indeed, if $u_n\to w$ is another sequence tending to $w,$ then $u_n-v_n\to 0$ and $v'(u_n)-v'(v_n)=v'(u_n-v_n)\to 0.$ Therefore $\lim_n v'(u_n)=\lim_nv'(v_n).$ The correspondence $W\ni w\mapsto \tilde{v}(w)$ given  by $(*)$ is linear. Indeed if $u_n\to w_1$ and $v_n\to w_2,$ where $u_n,v_n\in V$ and $w_1,w_2\in W,$ then $\alpha u_n+\beta v_n\to \alpha w_1+\beta w_2$ and
$$\tilde{v}(\alpha w_1+\beta w_2)=\lim_{n\to\infty} v'(\alpha u_n+\beta v_n)=
\alpha \lim_{n\to \infty}v'(u_n)+\beta \lim_{n\to \infty}v'(v_n)=\alpha\tilde{v}(w_1)+\beta\tilde{v}(w_2)$$
The functional $\tilde{v}$ is bounded and $\|\tilde{v}\|=\|v'\|.$  Indeed, by $(*)$ we get
$$|\tilde{v}(w)|=\lim_{n\to \infty} |v'(v_n)|\le \|v'\|\, \lim_{n\to \infty}\|v_n\|=\|v'\|\,\|w\|, \ {\rm as}\ v_n\to w$$
Therefore $\|\tilde{v}\|\le \|v'\|.$

The whole space can be decomposed as $\mathcal{H}=W\oplus W^\perp$ (*which requires that the subspace $W$ is closed*) We are going to extend $\tilde{v},$ which is originally defined on $W,$ to the entire space, by setting $0$ on $W^\perp.$ Namely define
$$\varphi(w+w^\perp)=\tilde{v}(w)$$
Then $\varphi$ is a linear functional on $\mathcal{H}$ and
$$|\varphi(w+w^\perp)|=|\tilde{v}(w)|\le \|v'\|\,\|w\|\le \|v'\| \,\sqrt{\|w\|^2+\|w^\perp\|^2}=\|v'\|\,\|w+w^\perp\|$$
Hence $\|\varphi\|\le \|v'\|.$