# Is there a non-Riesz way to prove the existence of uniqueness of this norm-preserving linear extension on Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem

$M$ is a linear subspace of Hilbert space $H$, $f$ is a bounded linear functional on $M$.

Proof that there exists a norm-preserving linear extension of $f$ to $H$ call $F$ such that $F(M^{\perp})=0$, and $F$ is unique.

I know the way to prove it using Riesz representation theorem like that:[questions/4445560](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4445560/prove-that-t-has-a-unique-norm-preserving-extension-to-a-bounded-linear-functi)

And I am questing that is it possible to prove it without Riesz representation theorem, it is hard for me so I came here for help.

Thanks if you can give me any advice of any form.

Comment: This is a standard application of $M\oplus M^{\perp}=H$.  You can try to prove it yourself. (There is only one way you can define the extension).

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4439340/constructive-version-of-hahn-banach-in-hilbert-spaces

Comment: @geetha290krm : Thanks a lot!